# Password incorrect importing certificate on 2012 server

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

When i try to import certificate on server 2012 it say password incorrect.

I have check this post:
["The password you entered is incorrect" when importing .pfx files to Windows certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343254/the-password-you-entered-is-incorrect-when-importing-pfx-files-to-windows-cer)

And i exported:
`openssl.exe pkcs12 -in 'C:\cert.p12' -out C:\key.pem  And created the new cert: openssl.exe pkcs12 -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -export -in 'C:\key.pem' -out 'C:\newcert.pfx' -name "newcert"`

But when i try to import in server 2012 keep saying password incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who need it, i finally got it. Before execute the command from the other post, you have to export .key and .crt from your .p12 or .pfx certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer in that post adds `-nomac`, which you didn't. Instead of turning off the MAC entirely, you could also try `-macalg sha1`.

--Something witty here questioning the use of a 10 year old OS (that only has 13 months of security updates remaining)--

Comment: My cert is .p12 i exported the .pem file, so i dont understand what the files .crt and .key do.